# Is There a Way To Make ActiveRecord Do A Multiple Insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a one-to-many relationship where one `Thing` `:has_many` `Elements`

I'm looking for a way to create a Thing and all its N Elements without doing N+1 queries. I tried:

```
[loop in Thing model]
   self.elements.build({...})
...
self.save
```

But it does a separate insert for each Element.

Answer (score 2):

This capability is not built in.

One option is to use a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), which will not eliminate the multiple `INSERT`s but will send all of them in one request, which will help with performance some. For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  1000.times { MyModel.create(options) }
end
```

To do a true bulk `INSERT`, though, you'll either have to write and execute a raw query, or use a gem such as [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/) (formerly part of ar-extensions). An example from the documentation:

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

I think this may be the best option for you.